# Postfix mail for mydomain.com loops back to myself Problem

Tags: postfix

I'm using vps server with ubuntu 10.04 when i send email to Gmail it's ok but for Hotmail fails, i check my logs i find this:

```
Mar 19 18:09:01 mail postfix/smtp[6340]: 8FAF722294: to=<root@mydomain.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=none, delay=0.09, delays=0.08/0.01/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for mydomain.com loops back to myself)
```

I look around inforums to find the solution but in vain even i changed my Postfix settings:

My destination setting was like this

```
mail.mydomain.com, localhost.mydomain.com, , localhost
```

i changed it to this

```
$mail.mydomain.com, localhost, localhost.mydomain.com, mydomain.com
```

i made many variations but still not working.

the output of `cat /etc/mailname`

```
mail.mydomain.com
```

the output of `postconf -n`:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain.com, localhost, mail.mydomain.com
myhostname = mail.dimonos.info
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 ip
myorigin = $mydomain
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Comment: You're not mailing to GMail or Hotmail. `to=<root@mydomain.com>, orig_to=<root>` Perhaps you're looking at lines in the log not relevant for your issue. Anyway, please include the output of `postconf -n` in your question and the output of `cat /etc/mailname`.

Comment: Ok i add it to my post.